# linq проверка процесса

Tags: linq, процесс, .net-4.5

```
try
{
  Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => new[] { "processa", "one" }.
  Contains(p.ProcessName)).ToList().ForEach(y => y.Kill());

   label.Visible = true;
   InfoText.Text = "Процесс завершен";
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
      label.Visible = true;
      InfoText.Text = "Процесс не существует!";
}
```

Как проверить процесс с использованием Linq?

Проблема в том как бы я не завершал процесс, даже если его нету, он пишет что процесс завершен

Как решить эту проблему?

Попробовал даже так:

```
new List<Process>(
Process.GetProcesses()).FindAll(
delegate (Process ps) { return (ps.ProcessName == "processone" || ps.ProcessName == "otherprocess"); }
).ForEach((Process ps) => ps.Kill());
label.Visible = true;
InfoText.Text = "Процесс завершен успешно!";
```

Но всё ровно пишет что процесс завершен

---

С таким способом закрытие 1 процесса, работает как полагалось:

```
try
{
   string target_name = "processa";
   Process[] local_procs = Process.GetProcesses();
   Process target_proc = local_procs.First(p => p.ProcessName == target_name);
   label.Visible = true;
   InfoText.Text = "Процесс завершен!";
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
   label.Visible = true;
   InfoText.Text = "Процесс не существует!";
}
```

То есть если в списке процессов нету нашего выводим `InvalidOperationException`

Comment: У меня есть 2 процесса которые нужно завершить, и при этом оповестить, остановлен ли процесс или же др ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему вы думаете, что там должна возникнуть ошибка о том, что процесс не существует? В случае, если процессы с заданным именем не существуют, они просто не будут выбраны для завершения.

`Process.Kill()` это асинхронный метод, он не ждёт, пока процесс будет в действительности завершён.

Для проверки того, завершён ли процесс можно использовать свойство `Process.HasExited` либо же ждать окончания процесса при помощи метода `Process.WaitForExit()`.

И я бы рекомендовал использовать сравнение без учёта регистра для фильтрации процессов:

```
try
{
    var processesToStop = new[] { "processa", "one" };

    var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
    var processesNames = processes.Select(p => p.ProcessName).ToList();
    var missingProcesses = processesToStop.Where(name => !processesNames.Contains(name, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

    if (missingProcesses.Any())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Процесс не существует! " + String.Join(", ", missingProcesses));
    }

    var filterdProcesses = processes.Where(p => processesToStop.Contains(p.ProcessName, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        .ToList();

    if (filterdProcesses.Any())
    {
        filterdProcesses.ForEach(p => p.Kill());
        Console.WriteLine("Процесс завершен");
    }
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Процесс не существует!");
}
```

Comment: Просто хотелось если процессов нету нужных, то срабатывало исключение `InvalidOperationException`, что процесса не существует. Попробовал Ваш метод, пишет одно и тоже при завершение(что процесс завершен)

Comment: У вас проблемы с архитектурой. В данном случае кидать исключение при обработке списка это не самая лучшая идея, так как отсутствие первого же процесса из списка остановит дальнейшую обработку. Сколько процессов одновременно должно останавливаться? По вашему коду их несколько.

Comment: Обновил ответ, пробуйте такой вариант.

Comment: По прежнему пишет что `Console.WriteLine("Процесс завершен");`

Comment: Я же написал, почему просто кидать исключение это не самая лучшая идея, особенно если присутствует хотя бы один процесс, поэтому мой код их не выкидывает. Обновил ответ, теперь код пробует завершать процессы только если есть, что завершать. Но всё равно, если запущен только один процесс, то будет выведено и ```Процесс не существует```, и ```Процесс завершен```. Модифицируйте мой код под ваши требования, все необходимые куски я предоставил. Либо опишите в вопросе ожидаемое поведение для всех случаев: вообще нет процессов из списка, есть все процессы, есть некоторые процессы.

Comment: Да сейчас работает как надо, огромное спасибо) Буду знать как делается))